# Correct way to process data inside of Backbone view template

Tags: backbone.js

Tell me please, what is best practice of data processing inside of view?

Example: I have a `User` model and there is field `age`. In this field is an age of user. It is an integer value - amount of months. And how can I implement this in my template:

- 17 => 1 year 5 months
- 11 => 11 months
- 24 => 2 years

Where can I store this helper-method? Inside of template is incorrect way. Otherwise I need to do some function that will generate correct model json. (not model.toJSON()) or extend existed JSON... Or ....

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two approaches.

You can put it on the model and then pass model to the template - it will mean that in the template you'll have to get the attributes using model.get('age') etc. but it will also make it possible to use helper methods for this model.

Another option is to have some kind of global helpers collection that later on you could access from your template like `helpers.verboseAge(age)` (don't know what templating scripts you are using so it could be it.age, this.age, age... but you get the idea.

Answer (score 2):

i gave an answer to a similar question months ago:
find it in this question [backbone toJSON with helper methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8225859/backbone-tojson-with-helper-methods/8230815#8230815)

it comes down to adding methods to the json, before you go to the template

like this:

```
var userModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this, 'fullname', 'toFullJSON');
    },
    fullname: function(){
        return this.get('name') + " " + this.get('lastname');
    },
    toFullJSON: function(){
        var json = this.toJSON();
        return _.extend(json, {fullname : this.fullname()});
    }
});

var user = new userModel();
user.set({name: 'John', lastname: 'Doe'});

// you will see in this console log, that the toFullJSON function returns both the toJSON properties, and your added propert(y)(ies)...
console.log(user.toFullJSON());
```

another thing you could do is override the toJSON method

like this:

```
var myModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
  // other methods and functions go here...

  toJSON: function (attr) {
    var defaultJSON = Backbone.Model.prototype.toJSON.call(this, attr)
    return _.extend(defaultJSON, {calculateAge : this.calculateAge()});
  },

  calculateAge: function(){
    // here you calculate the years and what not, then return it.
  }
});
```

and a third way of doing this would be to give the model to your template instead of the .toJSON() return. then you can call model.CalculateAge() in your template.